# How to keep equal space b/w views on all iOS devices programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting a very small issue in setting up my screen views equally on all iPhone screen sizes. Attached is the screenshot of the same. I want to keep the spacing (X) equal b/w view's top-view1-view2-bottom on all iPhone devices. What will be the best approach to do so ??

I tried to use view1 & view2 in stackView and distributed them equal vertically. But that way the logo image is also taking full width as of view's frame. I know I am missing very little thing in my code. But I am not able to get it rightly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Reference Screen]

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Stack Views to place all the elements vertically. May be you will have to use multiple stack views. i.e.

> `StackView1` would be the textFields and button
>
> `StackView2` would be logo and `stackView1` with minimum spacing, which is the consistent spacing you want.

2. Then make your `stackView2` centre vertically and horizontally within the container/superview.
3. Lastly, make `stackView2` top, bottom, leading, trailing anchors greater than equal to zero, so that it never goes out of the screen bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Put a two UIView. First is above view1 and second in between view1 and view2. make background color clear for both views. Put equal height constraint for view1 and view2.